# What does it mean? JS expression value = !1

Tags: javascript

I found in one JavaScript file:

```
value = !1
```

I am unable to understand what does it mean. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: [Did you google enough?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a short record `false` (not recommended to use, better to write full `false`)

```js
console.log(!1)
```